# Java - selecting a togglebutton from a String

Tags: java, string, togglebutton

Let's say i have many toggle buttons and i would like to change their state based on a condition, like this: `if(something){buttonone.setSelected(true);}`

The problem is, i have more than a 100 buttons and it would be a lot of time to write the conditions one by one.

Is it possible to get the buttons from a string and toggle the desired ones?

```
String buttontext="buttonone, buttontwo, buttonthree";

(button from the string).setSelected(true);
```

I'm new to Java, and i can't find an aswer to this.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using swing or javascript here ?

Comment: A HashMap<String, whatEverButtonType> will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the buttons into an ArrayList or other collection and use a for loop through them, setting them selected if they match criteria. Also as noted in comments, if you use a `HashMap<String, JToggleButton>`, you can easily obtain a reference to the button of interest by its String "key", and then do what you wish with it.

Comment: Ok, this is good, but how do i put my different named buttons into an array, without having to do it one by one?

Comment: @magus: if you've got 100 buttons, you're likely not creating them one-by-one but doing so in a for loop. Consider adding your buttons to the ArrayList at that time.